# How can I make a wrapper's css not apply to it's contained elements

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that has some opacity. I would like to keep it a container, so I can retain the automatic height. How do I retain the styles of the container, without them applying to all of the contents within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the opacity property this is not possible. If it's just a background color on the container the best solution is to use rgba() or hsla() for your color since they contain an alpha (opacity) value.